# Several Limit problems

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm trying to find the limit of the following problems, as $n \to \infty$ (put in one post rather than several posts). I've recently learnt the ratio test for sequences, so I believe this will be used in the problems.

1. $\frac{n^{1000}}{2^{n}}$
2. $\frac{1.0001^{n}}{n}$
3. $(\frac{x^{n}}{n^{k}})$ for $ x > 0, k=1,2,\dots$
4. $\Big(\frac{n^{4}11^{n}+n^{9}9^{n}}{7^{2n}+1}\Big)$
5. $\Big((4^{10}+2^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}\Big)$
6. $\Big(\frac{3n^{3}+n\cos^{2}n}{n^{2}+\sin^{2}n}\Big)$
7. $\Big((3n^{2}+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\Big)$

Attempt:

1.Let $a_{n} = \frac{n^{1000}}{2^{n}}$. Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{(n+1)^{1000}}{2n^{1000}}$. I consiered applying Bernoulli's inequality to the numerator to deduce it is $ \geq 0$, and then try to find an upper bound to apply the sandwich theorem.

2.Let $a_{n} = \frac{1.0001^{n}}{n}$. Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{1.0001n}{n+1}$. I'm not quite sure how to now justify that this goes to infinity.

3. I'm not sure how to prove this one. Maybe by induction assuming the limit is $0$?
4. This is $0$ since the highest power is in the denominator. But this doesn't really feel like a sufficent proof.
5. I'm not sure if this is permissible, but I learnt that the limit of $(x^{n}+y^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = \max\{x,y\}$. If apply this here, I get that the limit is $2$. If this isn't permissible, I thought about rewriting the sequence as an exponential.
6. This goes to infinity. Because the degree of the numerator is highest, but again I'm not sure if this is a sufficient proof.
7. I'm not sure how to answer this one.

   Thanks.

Comment: Note that for the second question, $a_{n+1}>a_n$ when $n>10\,000$ so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist.

Comment: You should post a single question at time. In this way answer to all questions becomes too long and less clear.

Comment: I can put it as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The general result  to prove is that for any $x>1$ and for any $k$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x^n}{n^k}=\infty$$

indeed by ratio test

$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^k}\frac{n^k}{x^n}=x\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^k \to x>1$$

from here we can deduce all the results.

Comment: Hi, I understand the above, but I don't see how from this, we can deduce all the results.

Comment: @AnalysisLearner For the first we have $x=2$ and $k=1000$, for the second $x=1.0001$ and $k=1$, for the third the case with $0<x<1$ can be andled by $y=\frac1x$. For the others we also need to use the main result by proper manipualtion (i.e. factor out the dominating terms).

Comment: For the first one $x=2$ and $k=1000$ so I guess we obtain $0$ as the limit (since we want the reciprocal). Also, the general result do we obtain it tends to infinity because $x\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^{k} \rightarrow x$ is for any $x > 1$?

Comment: @AnalysisLearner Yes exactly!